# How do i override the css style variant from an imported vue.js component

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I gotta little problem right here. I'm importing a vue.js component from a UI library (our own, custom one, managed with storybook) and i want to override certain settings to customize it only in this SFC.

How do i manage to do that?

I tried using `.parent` selector in the scoped css of my SFC but it doesn't work. There are no changes at all. Do i miss something?

`<Message variant="warning"> Further Content </Message>`

I want to override the component variant (using the component & the actual SFC i'm working in are using TailwindCSS).

Comment: Please add a simple code example that demonstrates your problem and could be run, so its easier to debug and answer your question.

Comment: What is SFC? `scoped` won't let you change styles from/of another component.

Comment: Single File Component = SFC.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html#single-file-components

Comment: which version of vue do you use? does the rendered `<Message>` variant have a specific class that's tied with variant `warning`? (like the rendered message has class `message-warning`)

Comment: Vue 2.7.x & yes, it has a specific class for it which is selected over the variant attribute.